# Meaning of "Why Has Love Got To Be So Sad"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw [a song of Eric Clapton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-NrOFLLMuM) in which he says "**Why Has Love Got To Be So Sad**". This kind of structure is a little difficult to me to understand as an non native English speaker. In the simple interpretation of words, does it mean (in other words) to ask "Why love happens to be so sad?" or "Why love has to be so sad"?

---

Edited:

1. Well, I knew what it means "I have got to do sth", but in this case the structure of "whay **has** love **got**..." is the difficult thing. I'd expect him to say "**has got** love to" if he wants to say "why love must be so sad".
2. By the comments here I saw that there are another version (that seems to be the original one) for the lyrics: "Why **Does** Love **Got** to Be So Sad", and for this version is even more not understood, since after an interrogative sentence in present simple tense should come infinitive ("Why **does** love **get** to be so sad") rather than past form (got).

Comment: The words ***Why love happens to be so sad*** and ***Why love has to be so sad*** are not questions. They're just ***noun phrases*** syntactically equivalent to *He told me **the answer*** (or, for example, *He told me **why love has to be so sad***.

Comment: FWIW the song is actually "Why does love got to be so sad", not "has".

Comment: To back up @hobbs, it's even right there in the video title and description. Honestly not sure where the "has" comes from.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to interpret this is to assume that **[have got to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have?q=have%2B%2528got%2529%2Bto%2Bdo%2Bsth)** means **must**. So this means

> Why must love be so sad?

---

Note that in both of the suggestions you offered, you have forgotten to do the subject-auxiliary inversion that is required to make a question. Neither sentence has an auxiliary, so you must add one - **does**.

> **Love** happens to be so sad. - *statement*
>   **Love [does]** happen to be so sad. - *statement*
>   Why **does love** happen to be so sad? - *question*
>   
>   **Love** has to be so sad. - *statement*
>   **Love [does]** have to be so sad. - *statement*
>   Why **does love** have to be so sad? - *statement*

Answer (score 5):

> Why Has Love Got To Be So Sad

What couldn't be so easy to you understand is the usage of **[have got to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-to?q=have%2Bgot%2Bto)**.

When you use **have got to**, you're saying that *something is necessary or must happen* in the way stated in the sentence.

In the question, Eric Clapton is wondering, in other terms: **Why must love be so sad?**

**UPDATE**

- > Well, I knew what it means "I have got to do sth", but in this
  >   case the structure of "whay has love got..." is the difficult thing.
  >   I'd expect to say "has got love to"

The structure of ***Why Has Love Got To Be So Sad*** is completely fine, because it's a question. For this reason, *have* and the subject (*love*) change position: *Why has* (1st part of have got to) *love* (subject) *got to*  (2nd part of have got to) *be so sad?* Another example is [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-to-and-have-to) (question form part).

- > By the comments here I saw that there are another version (that seems
  >   to be the original one) for the lyrics: "Why Does Love Got to Be So
  >   Sad", and for this version is even more not understood, since after an
  >   interrogative sentence in present simple tense should come infinitive
  >   ("Why does love get to be so sad") rather than past form (got).

I think *Why Does Love Got to Be So Sad* is completely **wrong**, or at least, I'd say that is something very informal in spoken English (perhaps American English), but it's anyway **grammatically incorrect**.
Take also into account that song lyrics don't always have a 100% grammatically correct English. Some examples [here](https://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/quick-english-lessons-song-lyrics-with-incorrect-grammar).

Comment: Clicking the down arrow without giving any explanation is always so helpful...

Comment: [not the dv] have got to be is not present perfect and [so easy for you to understand]. Have got is an alternative form of the present tense, used in speaking: to have or to have got.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and I agree with you that some explanation should be added while downvoting.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, indeed when I first read the sentence I mixed up present perfect with the usage of have got to. When I updated the answer the proper usage of have got to, I forgot to remove indeed that reference. Thanks!

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=xb6ie6PqYhwC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=is+got+a+variant+past+participle+of+gotten&source=bl&ots=25-q7fbqod&sig=BYLYhyKWPrpnaSA9tiy3f5nbNA0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ_KmLmoHeAhXMmOAKHUWkCo4Q6AEwD3oECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20got%20a%20variant%20past%20participle%20of%20gotten&f=false

Comment: @AlbertoSolano For you question "What couldn't be so easy to you understand is the usage of have got to.". Well, I knew what it means "I have got to do sth", but in this case the structure of "whay **has** love **got**..." is the difficult thing. I'd expect to say "**has got** love to".

Comment: Is this answer even relevant given that the OP misquoted the song title and lyrics?

Comment: I edited it. Please look again at the link, I put the original clip that I saw.

Comment: @Conceivableassessment Sorry for the delay. I see, I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why has love got to be so sad?

In English, there are **two present forms of the verb** ***have*** when it means to have an obligation or be necessary (to **have to do or be** something or to **have got to do or be something**) or possession or ownership (to have or have got something).

to have to be something can also be said as: to have got to be something.

> - I have got to go now.  She has got to be kidding.
> - I have to go now.   She has to be kidding.
> - I must go. She must be kidding.

The three sentences above all mean the same thing. What is confusing to ELLers is that the verb *have* has two forms in the present tense:

To have to be something=To have got to be something.

Why has love got to be so sad? [Third person singular, **has got**]. This line could have been written in any of the other two ways given above as well.

Please note:

> Please note:  *have got* is used in speech, not in writing. Also, I gave have/has got to be kidding because in English there is often another verb after have/has got/must.

After seeing the edited question:
\
Why does love got to be so sad.

**Something has got to be [something]. Meaning: have to be.**

Why has something got to be so sad? In colloquial AmE,they make that:

Why does something got to be so sad? and mix up the two forms.